# how to create camelCase fake in mocker-data-generator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this online utility to create the mock data, I need an help to create the data in camelCase letter. How to do that?

Mock Data Generator: https://danibram.github.io/mocker-data-generator/

https://github.com/danibram/mocker-data-generator

This is my script:

```
var cat = {
    id: {
        chance: 'guid'
    },
    name: {
        faker: 'name.firstName'
    },
    lname: {
        faker: 'name.lastName'
    }

};

mocker()
    .schema('cat', cat, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

i read some documentation, it stated that you actually can use a custom function, so add camelize() function and called in your cat variable.

please checkout my snippet. have a nice day!

```
var cat = {
    id: {
        chance: 'guid'
    },
    name: {
        faker: 'name.firstName'
    },
    lname: {
        faker: 'name.lastName'
    },
    camelText: {
        function: function() {
            return (
                camelize(
                    "my name is "+this.object.name
                )
            )
        }
    }

};

mocker()
    .schema('cat', cat, 2)


function camelize(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index === 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
}
```

owh also don't forget to test it by yourself at https://danibram.github.io/mocker-data-generator

EDIT: check the camelText value.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying like this camelize(this.object.name) but this shows all in lowercase not in camelcase

Comment: yes because it will only camelize if separated by space chek my updated image. however, in your case you can do like this camelize(this.object.name +" "+this.object.lname).